# Cómo modificar el layout de un control buttom?

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando con un objeto Panel SD. Dentro de él, coloque un control Button.
Y luego de modificar las propiedades que resalto en amarillo, compilé todo de nuevo, y me sigue apareciendo el botón con el mismo layout gris sin imagen.

Qué me estaría faltando hacer? hay alguna forma de visualizar los botones con otros formatos que no sea el boton rectangular gris por defecto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir una imagen del diseño que deseas lograr?

Comment: En principio deseaba ver el boton con una imagen del lado izquierdo del Texto.

Comment: Por otro lado, es saber desde donde ó como puedo cambiar la forma del boton (que tenga un marco, o que una imagen sea un boton). Una vez que hago los cambios estoy haciendo un Build All, y luego F5

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que queres lograr es un boton con imagen y texto, te recomiendo 2 formas:

Primera (mas recomendable):

No usar el control button, sino una Table con 2 columns, una que contiene la imagen y otra que contenga el texto del "boton". Luego le das estilo a la tabla con una custom class (tamaño, fondo, border radius, etc.).
Finalmente, para que funcione como un boton, tendrias que programar el evento TAP de la tabla:

```
Event TableSample.Tap
   //your code
EndEvent
```

La otra forma de lograr esto (menos recomendable):

1. Borrar la propiedad "Caption" del control button.
2. Asignarle una custom class a tu boton.
3. A dicha custom class, agregarle un background image que contenga la imagen y el texto del boton, es decir, el diseño del mismo.

Espero haberte ayudado,

Saludos

Comment: Hay una tercera forma que podria ser usar directamente una imagen (recurso de la kb) y asignarle el evento tap a esa imagen.